# Where should I get rpms for Red Hat Linux release 9 (Shrike)

Tags: redhat, rpm

I need a recent version of the C++ standard library (version 6).

What is the best way to get this on our RedHat server?  I noticed that `up2date` is not setup.  Instead, is there a standard safe location to download it or should I setup `up2date`?  I do no intend to update anything else on the system.

I think `up2date` may be over-kill.  This sounds like it may be a paid service:

```
Error Message:
    Service not enabled for system profile: "myserver"
Error Class Code: 31
Error Class Info: 
     This system does not have a valid entitlement for Red Hat Network.
     Please visit https://rhn.redhat.com/rhn/systems/SystemEntitlements.do
     or login at https://rhn.redhat.com, and from the "Your RHN" tab,
     select "Subscription Management" to enable RHN service for this system.
Explanation: 
     An error has occurred while processing your request. If this problem
     persists please enter a bug report at bugzilla.redhat.com.
     If you choose to submit the bug report, please be sure to include
     details of what you were trying to do when this error occurred and
     details on how to reproduce this problem.
```

Comment: This system is _ancient_. As such it should have been decommissioned _years_ ago. You're doing nobody any favors by expanding its use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the download tree for the Red Hat 9 distribution at: http://legacy.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/9/en/

The packages are in: http://legacy.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/9/en/os/i386/RedHat/RPMS/

You won't find newer versions of those libraries or packages, though. That's just a way to obtain downloads of any additional packages since you don't have `up2date` capabilities.

What problem are you trying to solve by updating the C++ library?

Comment: I'm upgrading to Firebird 2.5....

Comment: I see compat-libstdc++-7.3-2.96.118.i386.rpm .. The messages rpm install of Firebird has a failed dependance called "libstdc++.so.6".  I don't think it is a match.

Comment: The [libstdc++ in RH9](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/redhat-archive/9/i386/libstdc++-3.2.2-5.i386.html) will only provide `libstdc++.so.5`. You're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

You are running a ten year old OS that's out of support. Red Hat will not provide any updates, nor will you be able to find anyone on the internet that will support you. You will need to install a more recent version, such as RHEL 6.4. If you do not want to pay for RHEL (which I think you should, as you seem to need support), you can try one of its clones, such as Scientific Linux or CentOS.

Answer (score 3):

[RedHat9/Shrike was released in March of 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux).  It has since been discontinued, and is not supported, so there is no place to get recent rmps for it, because no recent rpms exist.

The currently supported alternatives are Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), which is a commercial distribution, or CentOS, which is a free distro based on RHEL.  Time to upgrade to one of those.